# While Scanning Barcode ,if two barcode appears at same time ,error should be returned

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, barcode-scanner

I am able to scan barcode and QR code ,But I need to show error when two barcode or QR code appears at same scanning screen.
I have uploaded an image ,In this condition i need to show error.
Error that i want to show "Please scan only one Barcode ." [image]

Comment: Problem, there are barcodes that made up of multiple 1-D barcodes, so whatever barcode reading library you are using would have be smart enough to identify that image as two distinct barcodes and not an incomplete one (or of poor image quality).

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks for your relpy , and i got output .
I am using Google VIsion API